# Необъявленный идентификатор в функции

Tags: c, функции

Не работает функция:
 int FindOtvet(int* a, int size, int *b, int size2, int*c, int size3)

Иницииализацию сделал абсолютно аналогично прежним функциям (функциям ввода 2массивов). Не понимаю, в чем проблема

Ошибка: array.cpp(58) : error C2065: с: необъявленный идентификатор

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *get_arrayA(int *a, int size) //функция ввода массива А через консоль
{
  a = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
  {
    printf("a[%i] = ", i);
    scanf("%i", &a[i]);
  }

  return a;
}

int *get_arrayB(int *b, int size2) //функция ввода массива B через консоль
{
  b = (int*)malloc(size2 * sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i<size2; i++)
  {
    printf("b[%i] = ", i);
    scanf("%i", &b[i]);
  }

  return b;
}




void print_array(int *a, int size)  //функция печати
{
  for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
  {
    printf("a[%i] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
  }
}


int FindOtvet(int* a, int size, int *b, int size2, int*c, int size3)
  {
   с = (int*)malloc(size3 * sizeof(int)); 
   for(int i = 0; i < size2; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
     if(b[i] == a[j]) 
      {
        c[i] = b[i];
        size3++;
        a[i] = 0;
        b[i] = 0;
        break;
      }
  for(int i = 0; i < size3; i++)
    { 
     printf("%d ", c[i]);
    }
  return с;
  }
```

Comment: Пишите английские буквы, а не русские. Компилятор считает, что английская c и русская с - это разные вещи... И еще - вы объявляете, что возвращаете `int`, а пытаетесь вернуть `int*`. Вы точно уверены, что так и надо?...

Comment: Так не надо! Спасибо за англ/кириллицу (исправил). Так не надо.. Как же тут подправить?

Comment: Возвращать то, что надо :)

Comment: return c; - и хочу.  Как в прежних функциях. Неулавливаю, почему *int вместо int

Comment: У вас функция объявлена как? `int FindOtvet(int* a, int size, int *b, int size2, int*c, int size3)` - как возвращающая `int`. `c` объявлено как? как `int*`. Что еще объяснять? Кстати, лучше вы объясните, ЗАЧЕМ вы передаете в функцию `c`, если его по сути - как аргумент - не используете? Как и в `get_array` аргумент `b` - зачем? если достаточно локальной переменной.

Comment: Я ее буду использовать..по-крайней мере хотел, в теле основной программы.

Comment: int n = 0;
int *b=0;
int m = 0;
int *с=0;
int h = 0;

 printf("Введите размерность массива A: ");
 scanf("%i", &n);
 a = get_arrayA(a, n);
 printf ("\n");
 printf("Введите размерность массива B: ");
 scanf("%i", &m);
 b = get_arrayB(b, m);               
  // описание вывода третьего массива через функцию 
  //вывод массива с  
 free(a);  
free(b); 
free(c); 
break;

Comment: Используйте. Передавать-то зачем? Вы же не вызываете, например, квадратный корень как `double sqrt(double x, int * arr, char * name)` на том основании, что будете использовать в программе `arr` и `name`....

Comment: Вот, из вашего текста - `b = get_arrayB(b, m);` - **ЗАЧЕМ** вы передаете `b` в функцию? Что она там делает такое, что она должна быть аргументом функции? Как вы используете в функции содержащуюся в ней информацию?

Comment: Все из-за этого: Я взял сэмпл с форума обозначенный как правильный, проанализировав, я также хотел убрать b (абсолютно с вами согласен), но в таком случае  выбило классическую ошибку  и я посчитал, что в Си так и надо: ведь если убрать b, то: get_arrayA: функция не принимает 1 аргументов

Comment: Мои потуги не дают положительного результата. Понимание избыточности передачи лишних переменных в функцию есть. Но исправить не могу

Comment: Да просто выбросьте и все. Типа `int *get_arrayB(int size2) 
{
  int * b = (int*)malloc(size2 * sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i<size2; i++).....`

Comment: int *get_arrayB(int size2) { int * b = (int*)malloc(size2 * sizeof(int)); for (int i = 0; i<size2; i++)..... c ретурном на size2 выдает на приведение типов.  return: невозможно преобразовать 'int' в 'int *

Comment: Cпасибо вам огромное! Усвоил сущность!